# How to sort characters in a string alphabetically using scanf() and saved character in buffer?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, scanf

Hi I'm pretty new to using C.
My teacher told me to code a function to sort characters in a string alphabetically by using array & the fact that when a scanf() a string, the first character is called and the rest are saved in the buffer.
(I haven't learnt about pointers yet.)

For example, if I type in badf and space(signalling "an end", or the sentinel value for end of string), the function should return abdf.

I'm stuck here. It's my first ever stackoverflow question! Please help. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char arr[100];
    char front_char, first_char;
    // set the variables
    int i, j, k, l;

    printf("Enter a string and press space to end\n");

    // get the input using scanf, which will just get the first character and save the rest in buffer
    scanf("%c", &first_char);
    // assign the first_character in arr[0] for initialization
    arr[0] = first_char;

    // 32 is "space" in ascii code. Space is used as a sentinel value. User is supposed to press space at the end of the String
    while(front_char != 32) {
        // get the "second" character from buffer and ass. repeat this until the next character in buffer is 32, or "space"
        scanf("%c" , &front_char);

        // load character from buffer, and check if its assigned number in ascii code is smaller than characters in array
        for(i = 1; front_char != 32; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                // go through the previously aligned array to compare the ascii number of the loaded character from buffer
                if(arr[j] <= front_char) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    // run through the previously aligned array, and if a character with bigger ascii number comes up,
                    for(k = i-1; k >= j; k--) {
                        // assign/push the values in array to the next index(i don't know how to describe this, but I hope you see what I mean..)
                        arr[k+1] = arr[k];
                    }
                }
                // assign the loaded character according its ascii number size
                arr[j] = front_char;
            }
        }

        // print the result
        for(l = 0 ; l < i ; l++){
            printf("%c", arr[l]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `front_char` not initialized and then also used in loop.

Comment: I am seeing `front__char` and `front_char` - two different variables, the former not declared, but used.

Comment: @AkashPradhan  Actually it is declared but not initialized .

Comment: I see top-of-block (C89) declarations, but also `//` (C99) comments -- Which standard are you compiling against ?

Comment: Thanks to you guys' help, I finally finished my homework! Hurrah! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get to your final solution, you have to get through three intermediate steps:

1. Read in the string successfully
2. Address individual characters in the string
3. Transpose characters in the string

You definitely have bugs (ameyCU's answer).

Try first to read in the string, and just print it out again; no other action.

When you've got that, try to read in the string, then print it out character-by-character.

If you can do that, you're ready for step 3 and almost done.

EDIT: also, when you get there,

```
while(front_char != ' ')
```

is better than `!= 32`; it's more reliable and much easier to read and understand.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

*For example, if I type in badf and space(signalling "an end", or the sentinel value for end of string)*

You want to take input as string ex-`badf` but your are taking input in a character variable.

```
scanf("%c" , &first_char);
```

Second -

```
while(front_char != 32)
```

Checking if `front_char` is space or not but `front_char` does not have any value stored in it.

Program will crash as soon as you give input !!

Comment: Thanks. You comments really helped a lot.

Comment: @Bossam You are welcome !! :)